# Convert the table PROCESSLIST from InnoDB to MYISAM

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I use MySQL. My database's name is "db", and I have a table called "Test".

I want recover the last update, so I used  this query:

```
SELECT update_time
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='db'
AND table_name='Test';
```

But the result is  NULL, so I converted my Table from InnoDB to MYISAM by using this query:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE db.Test ENGINE=MYISAM;
```

and it worked.

But the problem is that when I want to convert the table PROCESSLIST from InnoDB to MYISAM I get this message:

```
mysql> use information_schema
Database changed
mysql> ALTER TABLE PROCESSLIST ENGINE=MYISAM;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

So, is there another solution to know what is the last update for this table (PROCESSLIST)?

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place? That sounds like a *really* weird thing to do.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I'm working on an application where I want to list the user logged on MySQL server, and when a user change his name my application must notify me and all this things should be in real time
and I can't use trigger on system tables.

Comment: And why would that require to change the storage engine?

Comment: Because when I use this query :
SELECT update_time
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='information_schema'
AND table_name='PROCESSLIST';

I get Update_time = NULL

Comment: Try to run your select in auto-commit mode, or end the transaction using a `commit` before running the select. Could be you are affected by MySQL's default isolation level `REPEATABLE READ`

Comment: No, it's not about **REPEATABLE READ** because if I used this query :
SELECT update_time
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='Mydb'
AND table_name='Test';
i get NULL but when I used this query :
**mysql> ALTER TABLE db.Test ENGINE=MYISAM;**
and I do again the previous query i get 11-06-212.that's mean it's work.

Comment: When you alter the engine for the test table you *are* committing (i.e. ending) your current transaction (all DDL implicitely commits your transaction). What happens if you run `commit` instead of `ALTER TABLE` and then query information_schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way, because they are virtual tables. This is also the reason why you can't do anything with them, except for SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `log_warnings=2` to get "Warnings related to‘Aborted connection information’ and replication will be logged to MySQL error log.

If you are using MySQL enterprise then "[MySQL Audit](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/audit.html)" feature will be useful  as it includes login and logoff attempts, attempts to access a database or a table, changes to database schema and much more for each and every MySQL user who accesses server.